# Virtualization: pass audio and video from one VM to hardware

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

I have a Linux server at home for storage, development and testing purposes. I would like to use this server as a home theater solution as well. Now it doesn't seem like a good idea to run that software on the hypervisor itself. I'd much rather have it run in a VM, but unfortunately **the CPU does not support Intel VT-d**.

Is there any way to do this without hardware IOMMU virtualization support? Until now I have been using Xen, but I'm open to trying other hypervisors, as well as other possible solutions to my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Rapsey -- AFAIK Oracle Virtualbox doesn't require cpu virtualization extensions.

I'm surprised that your server does not support them, unless it's more than 6 years old.
Go ahead and check for sure if you haven't `grep -c 'vmx\|svm' /proc/cpuinfo`
If the result of the grep command is nonzero, then you have cpu virtualization extensions.  (the command won't work from a xen hypervisor console though.)  Also be sure to check your bios, you normally have to turn on virtualization support explicitly.

With all that said, I highly recommend [Virtualbox.org](http://virtualbox.org) , it's my goto when I don't need to do complex networking.  Virtualbox is extremely intuitive and will run on almost any platform.

Comment: It has VT-x support, but not VT-d which is required for direct IO. Product page: http://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz

You're right, VirtualBox would work, but I was hoping for a solution with a bare metal hypervisor. Everything else would run headless, I just need the display of one VM.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: VirtualBox can run headless as well.

Comment: Good point I meant to add that.  As far as bare metal goes, Xen, for instance, is based on CentOS.  It's not the same thing, but you could get the minimal install of CentOS 6 here: http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/ then just install virtualbox and run headless. There is even a virtualbox yum repo so you can download and keep up to date automatically.  http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox

Comment: Yes but the host OS couldn't run headless then, right? Or is it possible to attach the video and audio output to one VM on a headless server?

Comment: hmmm yeah the host os could run headless just fine, you would just ssh into it to manage things or use vnc.  This is basically the same thing you will do with the guest os's if they are headless, you will use vnc or ssh or whatever you want.  In other words, you wouldn't lose anything in this approach that you could do with esxi or xen.  If you are just streaming from it with plex or xbmc or something, this will be the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Are you referring to using virtualBox VRDP and running a client on the host OS?
EDIT: I've done some testing with VRDP. It works really well, but unfortunately, like most VNC solutions it uses compression that cannot be turned off as far as I know. This makes it kind of ill-suited for something like Plex or XMBC. I'm a bit of a quality freak I'm afraid.

Comment: You don't have to use the built in RDP if you don't want, you can use whatever.  Are you intending this to be the server or the client?  If you are running plex or xmbc server you don't need any "gui" since the plex or xmbc clients will connect.  If this is intended to be the client e.g. connects to the tv, then you will want to run a full gui on the hypervisor.  Better yet just buy a $35 raspberry pi and use that as your media client.

Comment: My intention was to have a VM for both client and server, but since the server runs headless anyway this question only applies to the client. I have tried running on a Raspberry Pi before, but I found the performance to be barely sufficient, even when overclocked. That's actually why I was looking into running it in a VM on a more powerful machine. It's unfortunate that the host OS would need to run a desktop environment for the VirtualBox solution to work, but I guess that's why they invented IOMMU virtualization.